# "ConvertPdbToMdb" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am using `Xamarin` in Visual Studio 2015 RC to build iOS apps.

As soon as I am using something like this in my code:

```
button.TouchUpInside += delegate
{
   // Whatever
}
```

I get the error, in Debug (in Release, it works) :

```
 "ConvertPdbToMdb" task failed unexpectedly
```

I found couple of discussions ans treads stating that it is a bug in Xamarin, anyone has a workaround for this ?

Comment: OK, the newest version of Xamarin solves the issue !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the latest `Alpha` release, should resolve the issue. 

More details can be found in here: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/121772/